# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <RevealController: 0xe9069b0>

Tags: xcode, authentication, uisplitviewcontroller, loginview

Im using a splitViewController on my iPad app but before that, i have a login and  when authenticated successfully I refresh the root and detail view. The problem is that once i load the mainview nothing happens, i try by pushing any views and there is no events.

And while I load the Login view modally I get this error: "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for

i do the login view in the mainview (frontViewController) by using this:

```
-(void)displayLoginView:(BOOL)animated{
 LoginView *loginController = [[LoginView alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:loginController animated:YES];
```

}

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
 [super viewDidLoad];

//Add logout button
```

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(logout)];
    //If not already logged in, display login view
    [self displayLoginView:NO];
}

```
-(void)logout{
[self displayLoginView:YES];
```

}

and appdelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

FrontViewController *frontViewController;

RearViewController *rearViewController;

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

 frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc]           initWithNibName:@"FrontViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

 rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RearViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
}
else{
    frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FrontViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

    rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RearViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
    RevealController *revealController = [[RevealController alloc] initWithFrontViewController:navigationController rearViewController:rearViewController];
self.viewController = revealController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

Is anyone can help me ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 13):

Check your `viewWillAppear:animated:, viewDidAppear:animated:, viewWillDisappear:animated:, and viewDidDisappear:animated:` methods, either you dont implement them or you have to call the [super viewDid....].
I had the same pb, the cause was shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation : one of them was returning false whereas the others were returning true, I set them to return the same an It was ok.

Comment: I had completely forgotten to call super in these 2 methods... I had a tabBarController with an embedded navigation controller, and in the tabBarController I had overwritten viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear but didn't call [super viewWillAppear] and [super viewDidAppear] and that's what what causing this message to appear, and also the animation to not being smooth. Thanks Abzamon, I hope you'll get your answer accepted soon :)

Comment: I had *exactly* the same problem as Roger. Thanks Abzamon, this fixed it!

Comment: not the right answer. it is more relate to view appearance by callee saying it is not receive correct appearance procedure.